# what is the most optimised video format for iPhone: .3gp or .mp4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm building an iPhone app for a mobile film festival. 
The app will make it possible for the users to watch the submitted short films over wi-fi, 3g, and edge (really?)
The movies will have a duration between 30sec to 2minutes max. (ste

Would you recommend using .3gp format above .mp4 ? Any reason/advantage to prefer one format?
I will manually re-encode all the videos for the iphone app.

thanks
Louis

Answer (score 3):

mp4 with the H.264 codec is very well supported at a hardware level

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cool app. iOS devices prefer h.264 video. For video to play in an iOS app on 3g, you need to encode them for Apple's HTTP Live Streaming. That's their version of adaptive bit rate encoding. Every Mac shipped with Leopard or Snow Leopard includes a segmenter with their other utilities, but it can only handle one file at a time. There's a help article on Apple's video utilities here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html

Encoding.com can also do the video encoding and segmenting for you. (Disclaimer: I work there. :) You can check out how to get this up and running using Amazon and Encoding.com on the site and if you'd like to talk to someone about it you can just schedule a free consultation with us. We're here to help.

Answer (score 0):

mp4 (i think the extension has to be *.m4v if you want it to use with itunes) with h.264 as codec

reasons: standard iphone format, better quality, better compression